# Split examples of a tensorflow tf.data dataset in graph execution mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

**Goal**

I have a `tf.data.Dataset` where some of the examples are too long (the size of the 0 axis is too big). I'd like to split these overly long examples into several examples, where each is a chunk of the original example. If a particular example is not divisible by the desired chunk size, I'd like to truncate the remainder.

As an example, if a numpy view of the original dataset looked like this (5 elements):

```
>>> print(list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator()))
[array([25], dtype=int32),
 array([ 6, 91], dtype=int32),
 array([15, 30, 96], dtype=int32),
 array([14, 45, 27, 72], dtype=int32),
 array([ 7, 75, 89, 47, 66], dtype=int32)]
```

and the desired chunk size is 2, I expect as a result a new dataset as follows (7 elements):

```
>>> new_dataset = chunk_dataset(dataset, chunk_size=2)
>>> print(list(new_dataset.as_numpy_iterator()))
[array([25], dtype=int32),
 array([ 6, 91], dtype=int32),
 array([15, 30], dtype=int32),
 array([14, 45], dtype=int32),
 array([27, 72], dtype=int32),
 array([7, 75], dtype=int32)]
 array([89, 47], dtype=int32)]
```

**Problem**

I am unable to write a chunking function that works with a `tf.data.Dataset` where all operations run in graph mode (as opposed to eager execution). Depending on the exact chunking function I tried, I am running into different errors.

Please note that I do know how to achieve this outside of graph mode, for instance in numpy or with tf eager execution. I'd like to write it as a `tf.data.Dataset` operation for efficient preprocessing of my examples.

**Code**

See also [this Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QKsedAF7zuUF0gygLgJIrkmKxjROgMRz?usp=sharing) to reproduce my problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from typing import List, Callable

"""## Code for chunking"""

def chunk_tensor_v1(input_tensor: tf.Tensor,
                    chunk_size: int) -> List[tf.Tensor]:

    tensor_chunks = []  # type: List[tf.Tensor]

    while tf.shape(input_tensor)[0] >= chunk_size:
        chunk = input_tensor[:chunk_size]
        tensor_chunks.append(chunk)
        input_tensor = input_tensor[chunk_size:]

    return tensor_chunks

def chunk_tensor_v2(input_tensor: tf.Tensor,
                    chunk_size: int) -> List[tf.Tensor]:

    frames = input_tensor.shape[0]

    if frames > chunk_size:
        remainder = frames % chunk_size
    else:
        remainder = 0

    if remainder != 0:
        input_tensor = input_tensor[:-remainder]

    num_splits = max(frames // chunk_size, 1)

    return tf.split(input_tensor, num_splits, axis=0)

def chunk_example(example: tf.Tensor,
                  chunk_size: int,
                  chunking_function: Callable) -> tf.data.Dataset:

    tensor_chunks = chunking_function(example, chunk_size=chunk_size)

    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor_chunks)

def chunk_dataset(dataset: tf.data.Dataset, chunk_size: int, chunking_function: Callable) -> tf.data.Dataset:

    dataset = dataset.map(lambda example: chunk_example(example=example, chunk_size=chunk_size, chunking_function=chunking_function))
    dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x: x, cycle_length=1, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    return dataset

"""## Code to create a dummy dataset"""

def create_dataset_with_single_example(size: int):
  t = tf.random.uniform((size,), minval=0, maxval=100, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32)
  d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(t)

  return d

def create_dataset(num_examples: int) -> tf.data.Dataset:
  examples = [create_dataset_with_single_example(n + 1) for n in range(num_examples)]

  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(examples)
  dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x: x, cycle_length=1, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

  return dataset

"""## Testing the chunking code with the dummy dataset"""

num_examples = 5

dataset = create_dataset(num_examples)

print(list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator()))

chunk_dataset(dataset, chunk_size=2, chunking_function=chunk_tensor_v1)

chunk_dataset(dataset, chunk_size=2, chunking_function=chunk_tensor_v2)
```

**Errors**

Using `chunk_tensor_v1` leads to

```
InaccessibleTensorError: tf.Graph captured an external symbolic tensor. The symbolic tensor <tf.Tensor 'while/strided_slice:0' shape=(None,) dtype=int32> is captured by FuncGraph(name=Dataset_map_lambda, id=140570786598224), but it is defined at FuncGraph(name=while_body_485049, id=140570787725264). A tf.Graph is not allowed to capture symoblic tensors from another graph. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it. Please see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#all_outputs_of_a_tffunction_must_be_return_values for more information.
```

and `chunk_tensor_v2` leads to

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

If someone knows how to further simplify my problem I am glad to edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit tricky but definitely possible! You could try something like this:

**Core part of the code (can probably be simplified)**:

```py
dataset1 = dataset.filter(lambda x: tf.less_equal(tf.shape(x)[0], chunk_size))
dataset2 = dataset.filter(lambda x: tf.greater(tf.shape(x)[0], chunk_size))

def body(i, m, n):
  n = n.write(n.size(), m[i:i+chunk_size])
  return tf.add(i,chunk_size), m, n 

def split_data(data, chunk_size):
    length = tf.shape(data)[0]
    x = data[:(length // chunk_size) * chunk_size]
    ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    i0 = tf.constant(0)
    c = lambda i, m, n: tf.less(i, tf.shape(x)[0] - 1)
    _, _, out = tf.while_loop(c, body, loop_vars=[i0, x, ta])
    return out.stack()

dataset2 = dataset2.map(lambda x: split_data(x, chunk_size))
dataset2 = dataset2.flat_map(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices)
dataset = dataset1.concatenate(dataset2)
```

**Whole code**:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(456)

def create_dataset_with_single_example(size: int):
  t = tf.random.uniform((size,), minval=0, maxval=100, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32)
  d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(t)

  return d

def create_dataset(num_examples: int) -> tf.data.Dataset:
  examples = [create_dataset_with_single_example(n + 1) for n in range(num_examples)]

  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(examples)
  dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x: x, cycle_length=1, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

  return dataset

num_examples = 5
chunk_size = 2
dataset = create_dataset(num_examples)
print('Before --> \n')
for d in dataset:
  print(d)

dataset1 = dataset.filter(lambda x: tf.less_equal(tf.shape(x)[0], chunk_size))
dataset2 = dataset.filter(lambda x: tf.greater(tf.shape(x)[0], chunk_size))

def body(i, m, n):
  n = n.write(n.size(), m[i:i+chunk_size])
  return tf.add(i,chunk_size), m, n 

def split_data(data, chunk_size):
    length = tf.shape(data)[0]
    x = data[:(length // chunk_size) * chunk_size]
    ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    i0 = tf.constant(0)
    c = lambda i, m, n: tf.less(i, tf.shape(x)[0] - 1)
    _, _, out = tf.while_loop(c, body, loop_vars=[i0, x, ta])
    return out.stack()

dataset2 = dataset2.map(lambda x: split_data(x, chunk_size))
dataset2 = dataset2.flat_map(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices)
dataset = dataset1.concatenate(dataset2)

print('\nAfter --> \n')
for d in dataset:
  print(d)
```

```
Before --> 

tf.Tensor([44], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([23 10], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([41 86  2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([54 78 20 93], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([51 87 96 84 31], shape=(5,), dtype=int32)

After --> 

tf.Tensor([44], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([23 10], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([41 86], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([54 78], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([20 93], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([51 87], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([96 84], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

`chunk_size = 3`:

```
Before --> 

tf.Tensor([44], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([23 10], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([41 86  2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([54 78 20 93], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([51 87 96 84 31], shape=(5,), dtype=int32)

After --> 

tf.Tensor([44], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([23 10], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([41 86  2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([54 78 20], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([51 87 96], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

`chunk_size = 4`:

```
Before --> 

tf.Tensor([44], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([23 10], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([41 86  2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([54 78 20 93], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([51 87 96 84 31], shape=(5,), dtype=int32)

After --> 

tf.Tensor([44], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([23 10], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([41 86  2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([54 78 20 93], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([51 87 96 84], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine. Thanks so much!

Comment: perhaps the leftovers of the chunk splits are not needed in the output? for example `tf.Tensor([51 87 96 84 31], shape=(5,), dtype=int32)` resulted in `tf.Tensor([51 87 96 84], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)` and don't see the `[31]` anywhere